# Smallest angle between two vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vectors, vector-bundles

I have a robot and I am going to turn it clockwise (negative degrees) or counterclockwise (positive degrees). If I turn the robot -270 degrees, that is the same as turning +90 degrees. Is there a way I can calculate the smallest angle in terms of magnitude to take every time? Is there a function that will take an input of degrees and returns the smallest (in terms of magnitude) angle to get to that target heading. So, if I input -200, the function returns +160.

Also, the modulus cannot be used because the input degrees can be a decimal and not a whole integer.

Here is what I have so far, I does not work for some reason:

Comment: Is your range of values $(-360,360)$?

Comment: Yes, I always start out at a heading of 0. Then, I have a target value between -360 and 360. Then, I try to figure out the direction which I have to take for the smallest angle to that target heading.

Comment: Could you try an if/else statement that checks whether abs(angle)=angle:  If it does, it returns the angle and if not, it returns 360 - angle?

Comment: Are you writing a program?

Comment: Yes I have to write one for my robot's turning function.

Comment: What about this: let $x$ be the angle you have, then let $y=sign(x)\times(abs(x)-360)$ and then the angle you pick will be the based on $min(abs(x), abs(y))$

Comment: That works actually. Thank you so much.

Comment: Slight variation:$$if\text{ }abs(x)\le180\text{ }then$$$$turn\text{ }x$$$$else$$$$turn\text{ }sign(x)\times(abs(x)-360)$$

Comment: This process won't work for degrees greater than a magnitude of 360. If I input an -810 degrees ( 3 X -270), that is the same as turning +90 degrees.

Comment: change to $ turn sign(x) \times (abs(x) (mod 180))$

Comment: is there a way to do this without modulo because I cant do a mod operation on floats (decimals) in c

Comment: ...why do we need vector bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
try
small_angle = acos(cos(angle))*sign(sin(angle))

Even if it works, you can spend less processing with an if-else...

EDIT2:
On Python, for example, it may be more elegant to do
small_angle=atan2(sin(angle),cos(angle))

Notice that atan2 is different from atan.

Comment: this does not work for negative values, acos(cos(270)) = 90 and not -90 degrees

Comment: @Jack, sorry, see edit.

Comment: @Jack, please see edit2.